# Why don't the Back and Forward buttons work as consistently in Thunderbird 3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, rhel-6

During the upgrade of my workstation from RHEL5 to RHEL6 Thunderbird was upgraded from 2.0 to 3.1.  I've noticed that the Back button (<kbd>[</kbd>) and Forward button (<kbd>]</kbd>) don't work as consistently as they did under Thunderbird 2, especially with RSS feeds.

Here's an example failure case:

- There is an unread RSS item, so I hit Next -> Unread Message (<kbd>N</kbd>) to read it
- I hit Back (<kbd>[</kbd>) to jump back to a mailbox message
- I hit Forward (<kbd>]</kbd>) but nothing happens; I am not moved to the RSS message

Previously, under Thunderbird 2, I was able to hit Back over and over, skipping around from mailboxes to RSS feeds to newsgroups, and then hit Forward over and over to get back to where I was.

---

Update: I looked around in Mozilla's Bugzilla and [comment #8 of Bug 533504](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=533504#c8) ("Back/forward history may contain null values and prevent the history from displaying") seems to describe my problem exactly.  In the failure case above, I see the following in the Error Console when I hit the Forward button:

> Error: An error occurred executing the
>   cmd_goForward command: [Exception...
>   "Component returned failure code:
>   0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)
>   [nsIRDFService.GetResource]" 
>   nsresult: "0x80070057
>   (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location:
>   "JS frame ::
>   file:///usr/lib64/thunderbird-3.1/modules/MailUtils.js
>   :: MailUtils_getFolderForURI :: line
>   128"  data: no] Source File:
>   chrome://global/content/globalOverlay.js
>   Line: 100